# Read image content using HTTP Get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httpclient

Below code downloads png image in angularjs 1.2.x,

```
$http.get(src, {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).then(function(data){
console.log("image content" + data);
});
```

after upgrading angularJS to 1.6+, not working.

developer tools / console logging not helping out either, because no errors in browser web inspector, log displayed output as empty response

your help would be appreciated.

Comment: usually, if something is *not working* there could be useful information in the browser *developer* tools console to indicate why it's *not working*

Comment: what does the data log say? is it api response or buffer? please add screenshot of logs / errors

Comment: More specifically, "not working" is never true: it's working exactly the way it's supposed to. It literally can't do anything else. So: [a good post](/help/how-to-ask) explains (a) what you set out to do, (b) the code you wrote to do that, (c) what you expected to happen, (d) what happened instead, (e) what errors, if any, you got, and (f) what you already did in terms of debugging and investigating. Right now, your post does not contain enough details to constitute a good question.

Comment: developer tools logging not helping out, because no error, empty response

Comment: you can try adding the `errorCallback` and that can help figuring out the issue `$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`